# Is there a way to prevent Visual Studio Code automatically hiding the "Add Code" and "Add Markdown" buttons when working with Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

When working with Jupyter Notebook files in VS Code, two buttons "Add Code" and "Add Markdown" appear below a Cell, when hovering over the location of the buttons.

Is there any way to prevent them from being automatically hidden when not being hovered-over by the mouse?

It seems like a bit of a strange UI design to hide them. I would find them easier to click if they were always shown by default.

Comment: So do you want to hide them or always show them?

Comment: @JialeDu Always show. *Is there any way to prevent them from being automatically hidden when not being hovered-over by the mouse?*

Comment: Submit a feature request on GitHub. But I think it's likely to be shelved.

Answer (score 0):

The only setting I'm aware of in VS Code to control the insert toolbar is `notebook.insertToolbarLocation`. Quoting defaultSettings.json:

> ```json
> // Control where the insert cell actions should appear.
> //  - betweenCells: A toolbar that appears on hover between cells.
> //  - notebookToolbar: The toolbar at the top of the notebook editor.
> //  - both: Both toolbars.
> //  - hidden: The insert actions don't appear anywhere.
> "notebook.insertToolbarLocation": "both",
> ```

It doesn't provide an option to make the between-cells toolbar always visible. If you want that to be a feature, you can [raise a feature-request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).